# FLAG_SECURE is not working for AutoCompleteTextView popup

Tags: android

I am using FLAG_SECURE for our activities to disable screen casting and scren shots.

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
```

When i am screen casting my app to pc i can see only black screen but if i select any AutoCompleteTextView, i can see AutoCompleteTextView  popup.
It should not show this popup when I am using FLAG_SECURE/.  So is there any way to solve this problem? 
[image]

Comment: That's a separate window. Perhaps `FLAG_SECURE` does not cascade to child windows, or not all child windows. If you have any dialogs in your app, you might try those as well, as they too represent child windows. I don't see any outstanding bug reports related to this. What device are you testing on, and what version of Android is it running?

Comment: I am using Nexus 5 with os version 6.0.1 and for screen casting i am using vysor.

Comment: Hmmm... you might try other approaches as well besides Vysor, such as Android Studio's screen and video capture tools, to see what your results are.

Comment: android studio's screen capture is showing error "Unexpected error while obtaining screenshot from device" but video capture is behaving same as vysor.

Comment: The "unexpected error" is probably a memory issue with Android Studio. I run into those from time to time. I'll try to set aside some time to look into this more tomorrow, assuming that you don't get any solid answers.

Comment: Thanks, I will post if I find anything about this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunatately, the Android framework sometimes creates its own
`Window` instances, such as the drop-down in an `AutoCompleteTextView`. Even if you
set `FLAG_SECURE` on the `Window` for an activity, the Android framework
does not pass that flag to any other windows created on behalf of that
activity. This affects not just `AutoCompleteTextView`, but `Spinner`, the action bar overflow menu, and lots of other things.

Authors of widgets or other UI elements that show their own windows need to:

- Examine the activity that those elements are a part of and see if that
  activity is using `FLAG_SECURE` to protect its contents. If it is,
  the UI element needs to apply `FLAG_SECURE`
  to any windows it opens up on behalf of that activity, such as a popup,
  so that the *entire* activity UI is secure.
- Or, the UI element needs to expose the `Window` objects via a public
  API, so that `FLAG_SECURE` can be applied where needed.

I have more about the scope of the problem, and some workarounds,
in [my CWAC-Security library](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-security/blob/master/docs/FLAGSECURE.md).

Thanks for pointing this out!